# How does LoadLibrary distinguish between different versions of the same DLL?

Tags: windows, dll, linker, dynamic-linking, loadlibrary

I know that when LoadLibrary is called, it checks whether the DLL was already loaded, and if so it increments its reference count and returns a handle to it.

Now say I have loaded MyLibrary.dll and then replaced the implementation of one function inside, or even removed it completely, and loaded it again with LoadLibrary. What would happen?

Based on what does LoadLibrary know that a certain DLL was already loaded?
What does it compare/check against? Is it just the DLL name and path?

Comment: *"Now say I have loaded MyLibrary.dll and then replaced the implementation of one function"* - I don't follow. Are you asking about changing the write protection, and writing code at run time? In that case, you are asking two different questions: `1` How are modules identified? `2` Does changing the code of the in-memory copy of a module change the ID of that module? Please clarify.

Comment: @IInspectable I mean if I change the DLL file itself (recompile it for that matter).

Comment: As long as a DLL is mapped into a process' address space, you cannot overwrite it. Your new DLL will have a different fully qualified path name, that serves as an ID.